# how to use find_if to find element in given vector of pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

For example consider `vector<pair<string,int>>`

**And it contains:**

ABC 1
BCD 2
CDE 3
XHZ 4

```
string s;
cin>>s;
if(find_if(vec.begin(),vec.begin()+3,cmp)!=vec.begin()+3) // I want to check only first 3 values
```

I need cmp to find given string is present or not using find_if

**EDIT:**
How to pass the string s with the comparator (cmp) and the vector will always contains minimum 3 elements

Comment: Replace `vec.begin()+3` with `vec.end()`. Your `cmp` lambda could look like `auto cmp = [](const std::pair<std::string, int> pair) { return pair.first == myString; }`

Comment: @Mansoor somewhat hidden is a comment mentioning that the vector's `end()` is not desired.  Only the first 3 elements should be searched and I suppose it's ensured somewhere that there are at least 3 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a lambda expression. For example

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::string s;
std::cin >> s; 

auto cmp = [&s]( const auto &p ) { return p.first == s; }; 

if ( std::find_if( std::begin( vec ), std::next( std::begin( vec ), 3 ), cmp ) != std::next( std::begin( vec ), 3 ) )
{
    //...
}
```

Another approach is to create a function object before main as for example

```
class cmp
{
public:
    cmp( const std::string &s ) : s( s )
    {
    }

    bool operator() ( const std::pair<std::string, int> &p ) const
    {
        return p.first == s;
    }

private:
    const std::string &s;
};


//...
if ( std::find_if( std::begin( vec ), std::next( std::begin( vec ), 3 ), cmp( s ) ) != std::next( std::begin( vec ), 3 ) )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But can you send this code without using lambda.

Comment: @matrix use a functor instead. If cmp is a function, I think you are out of luck unless you make s a global variable

Comment: @matrix You can use a function object.

Comment: Yes @CaptainHatteras . If I'm not gonna use lambda ,I guess the only option left is using functor.

Comment: okay @VladfromMoscow